# SQL queries: how to get the value which appears the most in the total of two different tables?

Tags: sql

Context: I want to know which vehicle brand appears the most in different accidents.

I have the table `vehicle (v_number, brand)`.

Problem is, I have two different accident tables:

- One refers to driven cars involved in an accident, let's call it `acc_drive` (`v_number, acc_number, driver`) [v_number FK vehicle]
- The other refers to parked cars which are involved in an accident, let's call it `acc_park` (`v_number, acc_number`) [v_number FK vehicle, acc_number FK acc_drive]

Now, I'm trying to get the vehicle brand which appears the most in the total of the two tables. For example, if Audi cars appeared 2 times in `acc_drive` and 3 times in `acc_park`, the total number of appearences would be 5.

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure this out, so a helping hand would be much appreciated!

Comment: update your question add (as a tabular text) a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1):

`UNION ALL` can be used to bring the tables together for the `JOIN`:

```
select v.brand, count(a.v_number)
from vehicle v left join
     ((select v_number
       from acc_drive
      ) union all
      (select v_number
       from acc_park
      )
     ) a
     on v.v_number = a.v_number
group by v.brand
order by count(v_number) desc;  -- put the biggest numbers first
```

Note that this uses a `left join`.  So brands with no accidents will be included in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT TOP 1 brand,COUNT(*)
FROM vehicle A
INNER JOIN acc_drive B ON A.v_number = B.v_number
INNER JOIN acc_park C ON A.v_number = C.v_number
GROUP BY brand
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```